# Is there any way to undelete a SQL server database and stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, database, recovery

Is there any way to undelete a SQL server database and stored procedures?

#### Edit:

No I don't have a backup. That is the reason I need help

Comment: Maybe this is why your developers try not to follow your standards

Comment: @TheTXI...actually i'm asking this behalf of one of the guys in the team.

Comment: At my job, standards dictate keeping backups.  You should evaluate your standards and fix/enforce them.  lol...

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi. That's not a live database. It was a couple of stored procedures that were deleted during development by the developer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Restore from backup.

You do have a backup, right?

Edit:
I'm assuming you probably did a right-click, "Delete" from SQL Management Studio? If so, that actually does a "drop" of the database, which literally removes the files from the hard drive. If this is the case, you'll have to restore from your latest backup (if you have one).

If you just did a "detach", then the MDF and LDF files are still on the hard drive, and you can simply attach them.

Comment: Nothing like that sinking feeling when you drop a production database.

Anyway, if you had a backup, in SSMS, right click on the server, and hit restore.  Find the bak file, name the database, and away you go.

Comment: You could get SUPER lucky and have a Shadow copy, ( right click on folder, and chooser previous versions ). But the UI is a bit hockey in XP/2003, ( can only see it through a network share ), and I know I tend to shut shadow copy off on SQL to cut back on the IO.

Answer (score 4):

How exactly have you deleted it.

If you haven't made any changes to you disks file system since then (and not defraged) then its possible the file will still be sitting on the disk as windows doesn't delete the file completely, just the File Handle.

Have a look at something like this and you may be able to recover the .mdf/.ldf files from your HD.

http://www.undelete.com/file-recovery.aspx

If not, you'll have to restore from your last back.

And if you don't have a backup... you're screwed.

Answer (score 1):

If you accidently deleted the database in SQL Server Management Studio by right clicking and hitting delete in a hurry and you have no backup then there might still be a chance of getting back the database:

1. Don't do any save / delete file operations on the disk where the database file was stored, browsing should be ok.
2. Find the location where the .mdf file used to be. In my case it was "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS2012\MSSQL\DATA". If you have multiple databases you can right click on an existing one, select properties and files. Find the location entry in the listbox under path (select and ctrl+c to copy it)
3. Download a **portable** undelete program e.g. [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds) to a USB drive/stick (unzip) and run it from the USB drive/stick.
4. Set the copied path as the "search location" in your undelete program (ctrl+v), recover "YOURDATABASE.mdf" and "YOURDATABASE_log.ldf" to the USB drive.
5. Copy the files from USB drive/stick to the original location.
6. In SQL Server Management Studio right click on "Databases" select "Attach.." click Add, select "YOURDATABASE.mdf".
7. Get some coffee and think about backups :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you drop the database or detach it ? If you've detached it then just reattach it again from the mdf and ldf files.